# Simple JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a simple array like `item_structure = {thumb, head, cont}` and here is my code:

```js
$('.items_options').find('#'+item_id+' .option .blog_item_structure li')
                   .each(function(event) {
    var item_class = $(this).attr('class');
    item_structure[] = item_class;
});
```

But it seems that expresion `item_structure[] = ...` is not working. So does anyone of you know what is rigt syntax?

Thx for your time.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. You simply have to learn how arrays work in JavaScript, which should be covered in every good tutorial. For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object or http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Comment: item_structure = {thumb, head, cont} is not JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean to `push` a value:

```
item_structure.push(item_class);
```

This adds `item_class` as the last element of `item_structure`.

For this to work `item_structure` must be an array, most easily made so this way:

```
item_structure = [];
```